# C++: Finding out how my computer stores bytes

Tags: c++, byte, endianness, signed, short

Got this assignment where we are going to check how our computers store bytes and so on and I can't really grasp how to get the correct answer, but the code pretty much explains how I am thinking.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

union hexNumber{
      signed short normal;
      signed short twoByte1, twoByte2;
      signed short fourByte1, fourByte2, fourByte3, fourByte4;
} theNumber;

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Write your number (int): " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    theNumber.normal = number;
    cout << "\nNormal: " <<std::hex << theNumber.normal << endl;

    theNumber.twoByte1 = number;
    theNumber.twoByte2 = number;
    (theNumber.twoByte1 & 0x00001111);
    (theNumber.twoByte2 & 0x11110000);
    cout << "\nTwoByte1: " <<std::hex << theNumber.twoByte1 << endl;
    cout << "TwoByte2: " <<std::hex << theNumber.twoByte2 << endl;

    theNumber.fourByte1 = number; 
    theNumber.fourByte2 = number;
    theNumber.fourByte3 = number;
    theNumber.fourByte4 = number;
    (theNumber.fourByte1 & 0x00000011);
    (theNumber.fourByte2 & 0x00001100);
    (theNumber.fourByte3 & 0x00110000);
    (theNumber.fourByte4 & 0x11000000);
    cout << "\nfourByte1: " << std::hex << theNumber.fourByte1 << endl;
    cout << "fourByte2: " << std::hex << theNumber.fourByte2 << endl;
    cout << "fourByte3: " << std::hex << theNumber.fourByte3 << endl;
    cout << "fourByte4: " << std::hex << theNumber.fourByte4 << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

They all print the same things.

Comment: Why are those bit-wise operations there ?

Comment: You might notice that `short` usually addresses **two** bytes not a single one. If you want to refer a single byte, use `unsigned char` or `std::uint8_t` from `<cstdint>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They print all the same because you use only `short` in your union.
What you might want to write instead would be:

```
union HexNumber {
  int full_number; // assuming 'int' is 4-bytes; int32_t would be 
  unsigned char b[4]; // uint8_t would be better
} theNumber;

theNumber.full_number = number;
std::cout << std::hex << (int)theNumber.b[0] << " " << (int)theNumber.b[1] 
    << " " << (int)theNumber.b[2] << " " << (int)theNumber.b[3] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `theNumber.b1`, `b2`, `b3`, and `b4` all access the same thing? It doesn't matter that they're on the same line. They would need to be inside an aggregate type (like a `struct` or an array).

Answer (score 3):

What you appear to really want is something like:

```
union hexNumber{
      int fourBytes;
      short twoBytes[2];
      char oneByte[4];
} theNumber;
```

Now a `hexNumber` object can be treated as either an `int`, an array of 2 `short`s, or an array of 4 `char`s.

Note, however, that the sizes of `int`, `short`, and `char` are implementation-defined. A more cross-platform version would be:

```
union hexNumber{
      std::int32_t fourBytes;
      std::int16_t twoBytes[2];
      std::int8_t oneByte[4];
} theNumber;
```

These types are available from the `<cstdint>` header.

Answer (score 0):

These lines: `(theNumber.fourByte1 & 0x00000011);` they don't do anything. The result is not stored anywhere. Did you mean

```
theNumber.fourByte1 = (theNumber.fourByte1 & 0x00000011);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have different data type inside your union and additionally you should add a bit field with zero length.

```
std::int32_t force_align : 0 ;
```

To make sure of the alignment.